# Convert Json array into normal json

Tags: javascript, json

This is my response:

```
{
    "item": [{
        "key": "name",
        "value": "john"
    }, {
        "key": "number",
        "value": "1234"
    }, {
        "key": "price",
        "value": [{
            "item": [{
                "item": [{
                    "key": "quantity",
                    "value": "20"
                }, {
                    "key": "price",
                    "value": "200"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

need to convert like:

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "number": "1234",
    "price": {
        "quantity": "20",
        "price": "200"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code and effort to try to solve the problem your self and provide [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: JSON is just text describing a data structure. If what you want is to consolidate your Array of Objects into a single Object, then all you need to do is make a recursive function that creates an object, and iterates the Array, adding new items to the object, like `result[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value`. When a `.value` is a new array, make the recursive call.

Comment: why do you have nested item properties?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newjsonobj = {};
var jsonObj1={"item":[{"key":"name","value":"john"},{"key":"number","value":"1234"},{"key":"price","value":[{"item":[{"key":"quantity","value":"20"},{"key":"price","value":"200"}]}]}]};
function recursive(jsonObj, newjsonobj) {
 for (var index in jsonObj) {
  if (typeof jsonObj[index]["value"] === 'object') {
   newjsonobj[jsonObj[index]["key"]] = {};
   var temp = jsonObj[index]["value"][0]["item"];
   recursive(temp, newjsonobj[jsonObj[index]["key"]]);
  } else if(jsonObj[index]["key"]){
   newjsonobj[jsonObj[index]["key"]] = jsonObj[index]["value"];
  }
 }
}
recursive(jsonObj1["item"], newjsonobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested approach for `item` and iterate all arrays and call function `iter` for every array.

This solution uses `thisArg` from [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Using_thisArg) for the next deeper level of objects for the result.

```js
var data = { "item": [{ "key": "name", "value": "john" }, { "key": "number", "value": "1234" }, { "key": "price", "value": [{ "item": [{ "item": [{ "key": "quantity", "value": "20" }, { "key": "price", "value": "200" }] }] }] }] },
    result = {};

[data].forEach(function iter(a) {
    if ('item' in a) {
        a.item.forEach(iter, this);
        return;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(a.value)) {
        this[a.key] = {};
        a.value.forEach(iter, this[a.key]);
        return;
    }
    this[a.key] = a.value;
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```